# Ajax Accordion in Visual Studio 2010, is there a solution to this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, accordion

I have a page that I am using an Ajax Accordion and when I run the site it works perfectly fine,  but when I am in the design view of VS2010 everything looks like a jumbled mess. The accordion is put into what to me looks like a list box, there are no panes to minimize, and there is a lot of scrolling up and down to look at the controls that are in each pane.

I am not sure if this is just how it is supposed to be or if I am doing something wrong, because in my work with dreamweaver(although its not an Ajax Accordion) I found that you could collapse each pane in its design view, and it would more accurately show the look of what you have just created. So is there any way to achieve this?

If there is any code that could be useful I can provide it, Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design view in VS is notoriously poor at showing things as they should be. Honestly - just don't use it. If you want to view accurate markup/controls in real time, just debug while you make changes. Saving the file and refreshing the page will show your updates.

Comment: thats what I was thinking. and it also has been the method that I have been using. I just wanted to know if I have been making it harder. Thanks for the answer